# Unicenta opos 4.6.1 can't connect to mysql 5.7.36

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, debian

Basically I can't get Unicenta opos to connect to a fresh install of mysql server on Debian 11. I have set up a user and granted privileges in mysql, created a new database named MAINDB and for some reason Unicenta won't make it connect....

Both the mysql-server and Unicenta run on the same machine.

a bit more info :

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          19
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.36 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 1 hour 34 min 44 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 105  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 143  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 136  Queries per second avg: 0.018
```

Unicenta settings :

[image: Unicenta Settings]

Error Dialog :

[image: Error Dialog]

More info from error message dialog box :

```
com.openbravo.basic.BasicException: Unable to connect to your Database Server!
    Please check User and Password credentials are correct
    The User must exist on your Database Server

    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 60 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 55 milliseconds ago.

    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

OS info (hostnamectl):
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-8-amd64
Architecture: x86-64

I had run the

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES * . * ON 'unipos'@'localhost';
```

and

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

after creating the 'unipos' user in mysql.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR unipos;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'unipos' on host '%'
mysql> select host from mysql.user
    -> ;
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| localhost |
| localhost |
| localhost |
| localhost |
+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below is from mysql's error log file in /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
    Version: '5.7.36'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-11-09T16:39:31.970790Z 2 [Note] Bad handshake
2021-11-09T16:39:31.981642Z 3 [Note] Bad handshake
```

I am guessing, there is a compatibility issue between the versions of Unicenta and mysql, however, I can't find any information on it. It is worth mentioning, that if I change the user credentials to the 'root' user in Unicenta setup screen nothing changes.

I can also connect to the database using the mysql command client with the 'unipos' user credentials :

```
jr91@Luke-deb:~$ mysql -h localhost -u unipos -p MAINDB 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. 
Commands end with ; or \g. 
Your MySQL connection id is 53 Server version: 5.7.36 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Any ideas ?

From what I have found I know that Unicenta works well with mysql 5.7.33, but this is not supported by Debian 11 (bullseye), not sure if that can cause the problem....

Answer (score 0):

This is a compatibility problem between Java and MySQL. A temporary fix is to edit the `java.security` file of your Java installation. You can find the solution [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205947/sslhandshakeexception-no-appropriate-protocol) in the first answer.